can ng-select dropdown work in mat tab in angular
I have mat-tab-group inside that I have 4 tabs, on 3rd tab I have to add dropdown, and also I want to disable scrolling ink behavior for this 3rd Tab, it should only be dropdown (ng-select) inside . How to disable the mat-tab scrolling behavior and only shows dropdown with the values there.

I tried this, but ng-select is not working

paste you code please  not a photo of the code
